# Led driver PWM modification

Tags: led, pwm, driver

I am working on to build a dimmer for led lamp. Led driver AC input is about 220V and output of the driver is 70V under load. I placed a npn transistor (mje13007) between led ground and led driver output ground. I am driving this transistor with a PWM source.When duty cycle gets bigger, it starts to flicker. What is this problem and how to overcome?

[image: Circuit]

Comment: What are the CV or CC specs vs load V vs I? The flicker implies inadequate supply or excess load current.  Should we guess?

Comment: The answer of Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams makes sense.Circuit fault and is shutting down

Comment: sorry for suggesting "usage fault" not circuit fault for not telling parameters above, but similar idea.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the driver is detecting the naive PWM mechanism as a circuit fault and is shutting down. The fix is to use a driver that supports PWM natively.

Comment: If I remove the PWM source and drive the transistor with a potentiometer,still have the same problem?

Comment: My point is that you *cannot* make this modification to the circuit at all. The output must *only* be connected to LEDs.

Comment: How does the circuit sense the modification?

Comment: It's comparing the current through the LEDs with what it *should* be. If they're not the same then it shuts down for safety reasons.

Comment: All led driver ICs have that kind of protection?

Comment: The ones worth buying, yes. But some *also* include built-in PWM control via an external connection.

Comment: Could you just be dealing with the perception properties of the human eye? I've seen where LED based Holiday lights that depend on simple diode/resistor combinations have a tendency to look like they are flickering when viewed from your peripheral (side) vision. After all, the MAX duty cycle in that case is only 50%. I don't know what's in your "LED DRIVER" box, but would it be possible to modify it with a full wave bridge rectifier?

Comment: Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, Tony Stewart and Randy. Thank you for all